# How to get ReactJS onDoubleClick to work with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, reactjs

I wanted to know if there is a way to get `onDoubleClick` to work with `IE11`.  `onDoubleClick` will work with Chrome.  I know that I can get it to work for IE at:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondblclick

I am unable to get it to work with IE when I create it in React.

```
<option key={index} value={option.value} onDoubleClick={this.onDoubleClick}>
                {option.label}
            </option>
```

Comment: Just tested com IE11 + React 0.14.7 and it works as expected https://jsbin.com/payegibuju/1/edit
Are you sure the problem is the double click event? Which version are you using?

Comment: @GuilhermeNagatomo    15.0.1  It is not calling my function setup with onDoubleClick....  I just updated your example to 15.0.1 and it works.  I will need to debug.  I wish you could see the react dom in IE somehow ?  F12 doesn't show it.

Comment: IE devtools doesn't work with react nor there's a plugin for it AFAIK. Try to see if `this.onDoubleClick` is defined. Can you update your question with a bit more of code or even better the whole component?